# ntfsfix error: Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk. After ntfsresize

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have recently used `ntfsresize` to resize my ntfs drive.

I then got an error saying:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/<user>/Win10: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda1" "/media/<user>/Win10"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0xaa4a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x2387f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

when trying to mount it.

I then used `ntfsfix` to try and fix it but it gave the error:

```
Mounting volume... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0xaa4a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x2387f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0xaa4a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x2387f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0xaa4a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x2387f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Comment: You need to use Microsoft's chkdsk software to try and fix the NTFS partition.  It is more powerful than `ntfsfix` and `ntfsfix` is not able to fix every NTFS issue.

Comment: Thanks but i can't get into my windowsh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to boot into Windows, or use a different computer with Windows if it's an external drive. Windows should automatically detect that there's an issue and have a pop-up asking if you would like to check the disk for errors, so just press yes and you should be good.

If you're planning on using the drive on Linux more than Windows, I strongly suggest that you use ext4, as it works much better than NTFS in Linux, as I have learned the hard way.

BTW, according to the manpages:

> ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

Comment: I can't boot into windows my computer just restarts.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Is there a way of fixing this without having to boot into windows?

Comment: If `ntfsfix` can't fix it, Windows is your only hope to fix it

Answer (score -3):

```
mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda1 /media/ashu/Shared\ Drive/
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Uuntu! Can you [edit] your answer and be more specific on what your command does and how can help the OP? To me, it looks like it just mounts the partition _read-only_, it won't fix the `Input/output error` the OP is getting.